# Shuffle a deck of cards and draw 2

Tags: c

I recently came across a coding challenge on some sort of technological basket weaving forum, where you had to pick 2 cards from a shuffled deck. I believe the challenge can be interpreted 2 ways:

1. Generate random deck, pick first 2
2. Generate sequential (or any) deck, pick 2 random cards

I went for option one. I believe I have used a good shuffling algorithm and accounted for modulo bias.

My main priorities:

1. correctness
2. code easy to handle and read

## cards.c

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <time.h>
    
#define SWAP_INT(a,b) {int tmp=a; a=b; b=tmp;}
    
const char const* suits[4] = {"Diamonds","Clubs","Hearts","Spades"};
const char const* ranks[13] = {"Ace","2","3","4","5","6","7","8","9","10","Jack","Queen","King"};
    
// from min inclusive to max inclusive
int rand_ranged_inclusive(int min, int max)
{
    if (min > max)
        SWAP_INT(min, max);

    if (min == max)
        return min;

    int range = max-min+1;
    int biased_interval = RAND_MAX%(range-1);
    int x;

    // prevent modulo bias by choosing a number outside biased interval
    do {
        x = rand();
    } while (x < biased_interval); 

    return x%range + min;
}

// Fisher-Yates (Durstenfield)
int shuffle(int arr[], int len)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < len; ++i) {
        int j = rand_ranged_inclusive(i, len-1);
        SWAP_INT(arr[i], arr[j]);
    }
}

void print_card(int c)
{
    if (c < 0 || c > 52)
        printf("Joker\n");

    const char const* suit = suits[c/13];
    const char const* rank = ranks[c%13];

    printf("%s of %s\n", rank, suit);
}

int main(int argc, char const *argv[])
{
    srand(time(NULL));

    int cards[52] = {0};

    for (int i = 0; i < 52; ++i)
        cards[i] = i;

    shuffle(cards, 52);

    print_card(cards[0]);
    print_card(cards[1]);

    return 0;
}
```

I feel like it can be optimized some more, especially picking random numbers, but reading from `dev/urandom` seems overall slower, when the modulo bias is so small and easily overcome.

Comment: I just noticed that I can do an XOR-swap instead of a temp variable. This would also allow the `SWAP_INT` macro to remain untyped. `#define SWAP(a,b) {a^=b; b^=a; a^=b;}`. Branchless check to see if not equal: `#define SWAP(a,b) {a^=(b*(a!=b)); b^=(a*(a!=b)); a^=(b*(a!=b));}`

Comment: Oops, just noticed shuffle supposedly returns an int. It doesn't. Should be `void shuffle()`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`rand_ranged_inclusive(a, b)` is a surprisingly long function name, for how little information it communicates to the reader. I have frequently seen versions of this function named `randint(a, b)` or `randint0(b)` — but where the possible outputs are between `0` inclusive and `b` *exclusive!*

Using "half-open ranges" like this has huge advantages in C, because C uses half-open ranges for everything else. To pick a random element from an array, you want `randint0(NELEM(a))`. To pick a random character from a string, you want `randint0(strlen(s))`. And so on.

```
if (min > max)
    SWAP_INT(min, max);
```

Here and throughout, I strongly recommend curly-bracing all your control flow, including `if` and `for` bodies which are *currently* only one line long. These braces may one day save you from a [`goto fail` bug](https://nakedsecurity.sophos.com/2014/02/24/anatomy-of-a-goto-fail-apples-ssl-bug-explained-plus-an-unofficial-patch/).

Also, I think it's un-idiomatic that you are going out of your way to produce well-defined behavior for `rand_ranged_inclusive(6, 1)`. I claim that that kind of input clearly indicates a bug in the caller, and you should be using `assert(min <= max)` here. (Or, if you switch to half-open ranges, `assert(min < max)`.)

Your choice to handle `rand_ranged_inclusive(6, 1)` becomes even weirder when you consider that you do *not* handle seemingly valid parameters such as `rand_ranged_inclusive(-10, INT_MAX)`. (The caller who tries that gets integer overflow and undefined behavior.)

```
int range = max-min+1;
int biased_interval = RAND_MAX%(range-1);
```

The use of `RAND_MAX % ...` instead of `(RAND_MAX+1) % ...` is an immediate red flag for me, after our discussion of half-open ranges. (`RAND_MAX` is an endpoint-which-is-included, similar to `INT_MAX`.) All these `+1` and `-1` would go away if you switched to half-open ranges. I bet they're hiding some off-by-one errors. Let's trace through a sample input.

Suppose `min`=1, `max`=6, `RAND_MAX`=10. (This is *legitimately* the first input I traced.) Then `range`=6, `biased_interval`=0... so the `do-while` loop runs only once before dropping out... but you end up choosing 1-4 twice as often as 5-6.

Did you test this code at all?  How did you test it?

I think the algorithm you want here is more like

```
int range = max - min + 1;
int discard_top_k = ((RAND_MAX % range) + 1) % range;
int real_max = RAND_MAX - discard_top_k;
do {
    x = rand();
} while (x > real_max);
```

---

```
int j = rand_ranged_inclusive(i, len-1);
```

Your Fisher-Yates shuffle looks correct; but notice again that you're having to add a `-1` to fix up the lack of half-open ranges in your random-number code.

---

```
if (c < 0 || c > 52)
    printf("Joker\n");
```

Is this situation possible? If it's supposed to be impossible, you should `assert(0 <= c && c < 52)` (hey look! half-open ranges!)

Also notice the off-by-one error in your code because of (say it with me) the lack of half-open ranges.

---

```
char const *argv[]
```

[I agree with Linus on this one.](https://quuxplusone.github.io/blog/2020/03/12/contra-array-parameters/) Prefer

```
const char **argv
```

Comment: I tested the interval by running (10, 20) a couple million times which produces 15 avg. And you are right, without the +1 -1 it produced slightly under or above 15, can't remember. ### My logic was that any remainder of the division would cause the bias, so choose larger than the remainder. ### The reason I went with both-inclusive, as well as such a verbose name is because such details always leave me wondering (is this random function inclusive? tail inclusive?). Thanks for clearing that up for me. ### I also like your `assert` suggestions.

Comment: Link to `char const *argv[]` is about a function lacking a size parameter and in that case, `helper(char *mcs_mask)`  is a good idea. Here, `main()` has a leading `argc`.  C spec uses the idiomatic `int main(int argc, char *argv[])`, so until the spec changes its style, `main()` coded as `[]` remains the clearer choice.

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica: Strong disagree, for the reasons stated in Linus's rant. The function takes a parameter of type "pointer to pointer to char," which is idiomatically spelled `char **argv`. You physically _can_ spell it `char *argv[]`, or even `char *argv[argc]` or `char *argv[47]` — they're all _physically_ synonymous in this specific position, because the language spec has special cases to make them synonymous — but logically you _should_ spell it `char **argv` so that the spelling matches the actual pointer-to-pointer type. Reserve the `[]` declaration syntax for array declarations.

Comment: @Quuxplusone The proposed new C principle for C2x [15. Application Programming Interfaces (APIs) should be self-documenting when possible](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n2086.htm) promotes VLA notation.  As with such style issues, best to follow your group's style guide vs. personal preference.

Answer (score 6):

### Premature optimization

> I just noticed that I can do an XOR-swap instead of a temp variable. This would also allow the SWAP_INT macro to remain untyped

That's unfortunately incorrect - xor-swapping in fact has a reliance on type. Aside from your declared `int` type, the "naive" implementation of your swap would work with (for example) struct instances where xor cannot.

Unless you're on a microcontroller that has a poor compiler and every nanosecond is precious, do not bother writing out a xor-swap yourself. An optimizing compiler will either do this, or better (with an actual swap instruction where applicable) for you. Your existing swap macro is fine, and if you want this to be type-parametric, you can always accept the variable type as another macro parameter.

### Parameter validation

```
if (min > max)
    SWAP_INT(min, max);
```

seems risky to me. If the application gets into a state where the min is greater than the max, I would consider this fairly surprising and erroneous behaviour, and would want to call that out as an error instead of silently fixing it.

Given that C of course does not have exception handling, your options to do this are somewhat constrained - you can have an output parameter separate from your return value, where the former receives the random result and the latter indicates success or failure. An `assert` would also be appropriate.

Likewise,

```
if (c < 0 || c > 52)
    printf("Joker\n");
```

seems too permissive. You should choose one well-defined value for a joker, and consider all others out-of-range to be erroneous.

### Random sources

Cryptographic-quality randomness is not important for this application, so I consider the `/dev` approach to be overkill. Something like the Mersenne Twister would work well because it has better numerical characteristics while remaining extremely fast.

Comment: Interesting. I thought the xor operator would just take whatever size data and xor the literal bits. Not so, then? Also, thank you for suggesting the Mersenne Twister.

Comment: No, for example `3.14 ^ 2.72` simply doesn't compile. Also, just as a practical matter, on hardware XOR-swap is going to be much slower than your naïve swap, because the former involves ALU operations whereas the latter is a simple register-rename that introduces no dependencies. Remember that the world is optimized for "ordinary" code; the more "extraordinary" your code looks, the less you'll benefit from the optimizations everyone else is getting.

Answer (score 1):

**Limited range**

For this application, shuffling 52 cards, `rand_ranged_inclusive()` limitations are not an issue, yet should be noted.

`rand_ranged_inclusive()` has trouble when:

1. `max-min+1` overflows (UB)
2. `RAND_MAX < range - 1`. (Note even some 32/64 bit systems have `RAND_MAX = 32767`)

Comment: This is a good note, I overlooked that.